# Add star rating from a product ID on some pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, rating

Is there a way to call to the star rating of a specific product on a custom page, at custom locations? In other words, can I add a star rating of a specific tshirt to appear under a picture of the tshirt on my homepage, for example?

I imagine I need to add some sort of php to my editor and then call it by some sort of html. I saw [this answered thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227121/how-do-you-add-the-star-ratings-for-products-in-woocommerce), in which, one of the answers seems to have helped people, however, it only gives you the necessary php, so I don't know how to actually put that on a specific spot on a specific page. I'm also not sure if that answer addresses the possibility of adding the stars on custom pages, and not just woocommerce pages.

Another one of the answers on that thread contains html. I tried it out and I was able to load the stars, except that they don't correspond with the actual star rating on the product page.

I apologize about the fact that similar questions already exist, however, they don't seem to address my needs directly and I'm too incompetent to make them work :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific *product ID* you can use some dedicated `WC_Product` methods:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Product Object (from a product ID)
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id);

// The product rating count (number of reviews by rating )
$rating_count = $product->get_rating_counts(); // Multidimensional array

// The product average rating (or how many stars this product has)
$average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();

// Testing Output
echo '<p>Rating average: '.$average_rating.' stars</p>';
```

---

**To display the product "stars" average rating:**

You can use the dedicated function [`wc_get_rating_html()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_rating_html.html#2753-2771) with [`get_average_rating()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#669-677) `WC_Product` method. So the necessary code will be:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Product Object (from a product ID)
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id);

// The product average rating (or how many stars this product has)
$average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();

// The product stars average rating html formatted.
$average_rating_html = wc_get_rating_html($average_rating);

// Display stars average rating html
echo $average_rating_html;
```

Tested and works.

> **An interesting answer:** [Rating is showing numbers instead of stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378284/rating-is-showing-numbers-instead-of-stars/49426458#49426458)

---

**A shortcode to display a product star rating everywhere - 2 code versions**:

**1) The best way** based on [`wc_get_rating_html()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_rating_html.html#2753-2771) function *(for Woocommerce 3+)*:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_rating', 'display_the_product_rating' );
function display_the_product_rating( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_rating' );

    if ( isset($atts['id']) && $atts['id'] > 0 ):

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );

    // The product average rating (or how many stars this product has)
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();

    endif;

    if ( isset($average) ) :

    return wc_get_rating_html($average);

    endif;
}
```

**2) The old way** (also works):

```
add_shortcode( 'product_rating', 'display_the_product_rating' );
function display_the_product_rating( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_rating' );

    if ( isset($atts['id']) && $atts['id'] > 0 ):

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );

    // The product average rating (or how many stars this product has)
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();

    // HERE the average width
    $average_width = $average * 16 . 'px';

    endif;

    if ( isset($average) ) :

    return '<div class="starwrapper" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__('Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce'), $average).'">
            <span style="width:'.$average_width.'">
                <span itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div><br clear="all">';

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE EXAMPLES:**

1) In the WordPress pages or posts text editor *(Where **`37`** is the product ID)*:

```
[product_rating id='37']
```

2) In the php code:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[product_rating id='37']" );
```

3) Between html tags:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[product_rating id='37']" ); ?>
```

You will get something like: [image]

Comment: Thanks for answering man, you seem to be the woocommerce guru here. Mind if i ask - how do i name this thing so that then I can add it with the add_shortcode function? I'm following [this example](https://torquemag.io/2017/06/custom-shortcode/). Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: Thank you very much man, but I hate to waste so much of your time. I just saw there's some short-code maker plugin, which has decent reviews and is compatible with the previous version of wordpress, so it might work.

Comment: @JohnHolliday I have added a better alternative code… please check.

Comment: That last update is even better. Love that it shows the average rating out of 5.00. Can't load the stars, though, but the text is quite enough. Thanks again man, you really are going above and beyond

Comment: Figured out the stars  - For everyone in the future reading this - [Check out this thread - it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378284/rating-is-showing-numbers-instead-of-stars)

Comment: @JohnHolliday Ok I will add the linked thread at the end of my answer as reference. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't thank me man, you are the one that deserves thanks