# Get product reviews average rating in a custom WooCommerce repport

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to display a report (HTML Table) for each product in something like:

[image]

Based on *"[Display total customers reviews and ratings average in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613317/display-total-customers-reviews-and-ratings-average-in-woocommerce/50614786#50614786)"* answer code, which gets the product average rating this way:

```
echo products_rating_average_html();
```

How to can I get the average rating for each product individually…  for example if the product have 4 or 5 reviews it get the average rating for them (For every product)

I also would like to get the comment review for every product to put them in the table as well…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123797/add-star-rating-from-a-product-id-on-some-pages-in-woocommerce/52123870#52123870), where you'll see that you can use `WC_Product` methods  like:

- `get_average_rating()`
- `get_rating_counts()`…

Here is a complete example:

1) Get the products required related data (customizable):

```
$products_data = []; // Initializing

$products = wc_get_products( ['limit' => -1] ); // Get all WC_Product objects

// Loop through products -- Preparing data to be displayed
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // 1. Product data as product name …
    $products_data[$product_id]['name'] = $product->get_name();


    // 2. Average rating and rating count
    $products_data[$product_id]['rating'] = (float) $product->get_average_rating();
    $products_data[$product_id]['count']  = (int) $product->get_rating_count();

    // 3. Reviews -- Loop though product reviews
    foreach( get_approved_comments( $product_id ) as $review ) {
        if( $review->comment_type === 'review' ) {
            $products_data[$product_id]['reviews'][] = (object) [
                'author'    => $review->comment_author,
                'email'     => $review->comment_author_email,
                'date'      => strtotime($review->comment_date),
                'content'   => $review->comment_content,
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

2) Customizable display in a table:

```
echo '<table class="products-reviews-ratings"><tr>
    <th>'.__("ID").'</th>
    <th>'.__("Name").'</th>
    <th>'.__("Rating").'</th>
    <th>'.__("count").'</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">'.__("Reviews (author, date and content)").'</th>
</tr>';

foreach ($products_data as $product_id => $data){
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$product_id.'</td>
        <td>'.$data['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['rating'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['count'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">';

    if( isset($data['reviews']) && $data['reviews'] > 0 ) {
        echo '<table>';

        // Loop through reviews
        foreach ($data['reviews'] as $review ){
            echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="mailto:'.$review->email.'">'.$review->author.'</a></td>
                <td>'.date( 'Y-m-d', $review->date ).'</td>
                <td>'.$review->content.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        _e('No reviews yet');
    }

    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Wow man i am speechless thank you very much you always help me wgen i give up many thanks for your perfect answes

Answer (score 2):

This will give the avarage rating of given product id

```
$rating = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_average_rating', true );
```

You can use this in loop of product this will give you a raw number of avrage rating without any html

For getting latest comment you can use below add this code in functions.php and then call this action where you want to display latest comment pass current product object as argument

```
function display_product_review($product_id) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $comments = get_approved_comments( $product->id );

    $product_link = '/product/' . $product->post->post_name . "/#tab-reviews/";

    if ( !empty ($comments) ) {
        echo $comments[0]->comment_content . '<br><a href="'. $product_link . '">Read more reviews...</a>';
    } else {
        echo "There are no reviews for this product yet. Would you like to <a href='" . $product_link ."'>add your own review</a>?";       
    }
}

add_action('get_latest_review','display_product_review');
```

Calling of action

```
do_action('get_latest_review',$product);
```

Comment: What about the comments ? how to get them

Comment: hello sorry im new what do you mean by product object?
i want to get this data for all products i have in the website how to achive this?

Comment: Hi i have updated the answer now you have to pass product id only

Comment: i pass the product id like `do_action('get_latest_review',145);`
product/coconut-milk-zumra-17-18-fat-400-ml/#comment-70
i still get There are no reviews for this product yet. Would you like to add your own review?

Comment: `function display_product_review($product_id) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    echo "sdfsdfsfsd" . $product;
}
do_action('get_latest_review',145);` doesn't return anything

Comment: The product id that you are passing have comments on it are you sure

Comment: Yes the problem is  even here `echo "There are no reviews for this product yet. Would you like to <a href='" . $product_link ."'>add your own review</a>?"` it doesn't return the $product_link it only returns
There are no reviews for this product yet. Would you like to add your own review?
without the product_link

Comment: are you calling this "do_action('get_latest_review',$product); "at where you want to print latest comment or you are calling this in function file?